# Grouping in a sorted asp:GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grouping

I need a grouping in a sorted asp:Gridview like the following picture shows:

[image: Example for Grouping]

Can someone give me a hint about how to proceed? Is it possible to group on RowBound somehow?

Comment: The user asks for Grouping - the grid is already sorted (see Screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following algorithm to do your work:

```
            /****************************************
             * Grouping Algorithmus 
             * by Björn Karpenstein
             * http://www.capri-soft.de/blog
             ****************************************/
            // Nach dieser Spalte soll gruppiert werden
            int k = 1;

            // Für alle Zeilen (VON UNTEN NACH OBEN)
            for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
                GridViewRow previousRow = GridView1.Rows[i - 1];
                // Für alle Spalten
                for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    if ((row.Cells[k].Text == previousRow.Cells[k].Text) && (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text))
                    {
                        if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                            {
                                previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                            }
                            row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the RowDataBound event. You have to remember that `rowspan` and the removal of the next cell has to be done backwards since the next row does not exist yet. `row["myValue"]` is the column containing the values that need to be compared.

```
string groupValue = string.Empty;
int rowSpanCount = 1;

//change this to the column index that needs spanning
int columnIndex = 6;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the current row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //get the current row number
        int currentRow = e.Row.DataItemIndex;

        //cast the current row to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //check if the groupValue equals the current row, if so +1 rowspan in needed
        if (groupValue == row["myValue"].ToString())
        {
            rowSpanCount++;
        }
        else if (currentRow > 1 && rowSpanCount > 1)
        {
            //apply rowspan to the first cell
            GridView1.Rows[currentRow - rowSpanCount].Cells[columnIndex].RowSpan = rowSpanCount;

            //remove the spanned rows
            for (int i = 1; i < rowSpanCount; i++)
            {
                GridView1.Rows[currentRow - (rowSpanCount - i)].Cells.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
            }

            //reset the rowSpanCount
            rowSpanCount = 1;
        }

        //set the groupValue variable for value comparison in the next row
        groupValue = row["myValue"].ToString();
    }
}
```