# How to make rowspan in listview?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview

I have a listview(not a gridview) and i want to put same results in one cell.
I can't make it with rowspan like in gridview, because listview didn't have this method.
What i have now :

```
FullName  | LgotName | 
------------------------                           
John      |First     |                        
John      |Second    |                          
John      |Third     |
```

What i want to have

```
FullName  | LgotName | 
------------------------                           
John      |First     |
          |----------|            
          |Second    | 
          |----------| 
          |Third     | 
------------------------ (this is end of John row)
```

My code:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"... >
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div class="outerContainer">
                        <table id="docnewTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Full Name</th>
                                    <th>LgotName</th>
                                <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Item.fam_v %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.im_v %></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="ChangeDocBtn" runat="server"  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="DeleteDocBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete  />
      </td>
     </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
```

I think about loop - select one value, and skip 1 , but it not very effective.

I use Asp.net, EF, linq

My Select method in c#  :
            I

```
Enumerable<FinalDoc> fidn = from post in repository.doctors
                                             join meta in repository.DoctorsLG on post.pcod equals meta.pcod
                                             join thir in repository.SP_lgota on meta.idGK equals thir.C_LGT
                                             where post.actual == 1                                                  select new FinalDoc
                                             {
                                                 mcod = post.mcod,
                                                 pcod = post.pcod,
                                                 c_ogrn = post.c_ogrn,
                                                 fam_v = post.fam_v,
                                                 im_v = post.im_v,
                                                 ot_v = post.ot_v,
                                                 idGK = meta.idGK,
                                                    LgotName = thir.LgotName
                                             }
```

PLEASE READ IT CLEARLY . 
 How can i combine my results to make rowspan ?
If i just write rowspan i will add SAMPLE RESULTS , and i need to add it like : value with index[0], value with index[1], value with index[2].

Comment: What you want is a [`rowspan`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_td_rowspan.asp) not `colspan`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)

Comment: @Liam its not a duplicate. Its another question

Comment: I'm not sure you can inside a `ListView `. The problem is that the `<td>` tag that should contain the `rowspan` is already created and you don't know how much rows to span. use a `GridView` and take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41570288/5836671

Comment: @VDWWD i know how to do it in gridview . But i need a method for listview  .

Comment: @VDWWD i can count number of rows for rowspan , in this case, if i will know number of rows, i can do it in listview?

Comment: you can add listview inside listview and bind it.

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt can you please write in solution syntax of this ? I just write asp:listview and go , or it has another syntax?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but you have to know beforehand how many rows need spanning. If it is 3 every time then there is no problem. But if it can vary then it becomes very difficult.

Comment: I just created a sample code to explain what I mean, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"... >
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div class="outerContainer">
                                <table id="docnewTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Full Name</th>
                                            <th>LgotName</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# Item.fam_v %></td>
                         <td>       
        // Place new Listview here like
       <table> <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
<tr>
<td><%# Item.im_v %></td>
</tr>
</asp:ListView>
</table>
</td>

                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="ChangeDocBtn" runat="server"  />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteDocBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete  />
              </td>
             </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:ListView>
```

Bind the data on Itemdatabound event of ListView1.

Comment: I have  datakeyname pcod, and i take it from      public void ListView1_UpdateItem(string pcod)
        {
            pcodik = pcod;
            GetDoctors();
        }   . How i can bind it if i didn't know datakeyname (column of my table) ?